# UK visa for parent of EU citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, eu-citizens

It's come to my notice that getting a dependent visa for a parent of an EU citizen for the UK is very difficult. Does anyone have any knowledge in this matter?
I am a Portuguese citizen and would like to get my mother(who is Indian) to come and live with me in the UK because she is a widow and I am the only child she has.
Can anyone help me or point in towards the right direction please.

Comment: For permanent immigration, you should ask on Expatriates SE.

Comment: In that case could anyone move the question there?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no "quick-migrate" option to Expatriates.SE, since it's still in beta (and even if it wasn't, a "quick-migrate" option wouldn't be automatic.)  A mod might be able to do it for you, but you're probably better off just re-posting the question over there yourself.